# Params become plural/incorrect on render after failing validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

So I have a weird issue that I can't seem to figure out. Basically `params[:order_id]` becomes `params[:orderS_id]` upon form submit which causes errors if the form fails validations.

I am using cocoon for nested forms on a page that has custom edit/update controller actions (because I need to control what happens upon successful/failed submits differently on this page than for the same forms on other pages).

**`params on page load`**

```
Started GET "/properties/99/orders/1/prop_order_wiz" for 127.0.0.1 at 
2017-08-20 17:33:41 -0400
Processing by PropertiesController#prop_order_edit as HTML
Parameters: {"property_id"=>"99", "order_id"=>"1"}
```

So the page loads with `params[:order_id]` as expected and I use this value in the following form:

**`deeds form`**

```
<%= bootstrap_nested_form_for(@properties, url: prop_order_update_patch_path(@properties, @orders), method: "patch", layout: :horizontal) do |f| %>
  ...

  ## Cocoon fields_for _deeds_fields.html.erb... ##
    <%= f.hidden_field :order_id, value: params[:order_id] %>
  ## end cocoon ##
  ...
  <%= f.submit "Save Deeds", class: "btn btn-primary inline pull-right" %>
<% end %>
```

Upon first render of page and a successful submit, everything is fine. However, if the form fails validations, the page will render with `params[:orders_id]` which leaves `params[:order_id]` blank and then causes errors.

I can tell from the following `parameters` submitted through the form that it submits with `orders_id => 1`, instead of `order_id => 1`, why does this happen?

**`form params`** (scroll all the way right to see what I mean)

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"..", "property"=>{ "deeds_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "property_id"=>"99", "order_id"=>"1", ..., "id"=>"1"}}}, "commit"=>"Save Deeds", "property_id"=>"99", "orders_id"=>"1"}
```

In my controller action I'll call `@orders = Order.find(params[:orders_id])` above the `render` after `@properties.save` fails but then when it renders `params[:order_id]` is blank and `params[:orderS_id]` has the correct info.

I've been able to work around this by calling `params[:orders_id] = params[:order_id]` in my initial load action but this doesn't seem the correct way to go about it. Can anyone tell me **why** this happens and **how** to fix it? I'll include my custom controller actions below for details. Thanks in advance!

**Custom controller actions**

```
def prop_order_edit ## Initial page load
  @properties = Property.find(params[:property_id])
  @orders = @properties.orders.find(params[:order_id])
  params[:orders_id] = params[:order_id]    ## temp fix ##
  render 'orders/orderprocess/prop_order_wiz'
end

def prop_order_update ## Custom update action for form submission
  @properties = Property.find(params[:property_id])
  @orders = Order.find(params[:orders_id]) ## modified for temp fix
  @properties.update_attributes(property_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
                  if @properties.save
                    flash[:success] = "Order Updated Successfully"
                    redirect_to prop_order_wiz_path(@properties, @orders)
                  else
                    @orders = Order.find(params[:orders_id]) ## modified for temp fix
                    render 'orders/orderprocess/prop_order_wiz'
                  end
                 }
    format.js {
                if @properties.save
                  flash[:success] = "Order Updated Successfully"
                else
                  @orders = Order.find(params[:orders_id]) ## modified for temp fix
                  flash.now[:danger] = "Unable to Update Order"
                  render 'orders/orderprocess/prop_order_wiz'
                end
            }
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the complete form?

Comment: The `bootstrap_nested_form_for` command does not use cocoon but `nested_form`. So it is best not to mix those. Also both those gems are pretty outdated, I would recommend `simple_form` instead (which has bootstrap support as well). 

Anyway: the problem is not related to `cocoon` or `nested_form` (building a form with nested attributes) but it is related to your routes definition (or your form url). Could you explain what you are trying to do? Your form-url = `prop_order_update_patch_path(@properties, @orders)` so it seems you want to hand an array of orders, hence `orders_id`.

Comment: Ah interesting to know about the gems, thanks for that. I've only been coding in rails for about 6 months now and the `bootstrap_form_for` gem was what I chose first when I started and kind of never switched. Basically `@orders` belongs to `@properites` so the route is `/properties/:property_id/orders/:order_id/prop_order_wiz` for the series of forms using `jQuery steps` plugins to fill out an 'order'. What I'm trying to do is pass `:order_id` onto the new `deed` record which also `belongs_to Property`, and that works fine on first load but if the deed fails validation it results in the above

Comment: I think the plural form is confusing the most: you write `@properties` and `@orders` --> how are those set? Shouldn't those be singular? If `@orders` is an array, it explains why the url is built differently (turns into `orders_id`)

Comment: I kept the same naming convention as what my resource routes are. Like I have `resources :properties do resources :orders, :deeds, :etc end` which are based off my controller names where the names are pluralized, I figured that's how it was supposed to be done. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the relation between **Property** model and **Order** model is has_many which will generate plural param when submitting the form.
If the property has only one order you will need to change the relation to has_one and then you will need to change orders to order then you can user order_id.

Comment: You're absolute correct, **Property** is `has_many :orders` and **Order** is `belongs_to` for those associations. I had no idea that would make a difference in params, so I'm glad you caught it. What would be the best way to rectify the situation?